# Find the equation of an ellipse given the eccentricity and the distance between the directrices

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

> Find the equation of an ellipse with eccentricity $\frac{1}{2}$ and distance $24$ between the directrices.

The answer in the book is
$$3x^2 + 4y^2 = 108$$

I already know how to get the first and second terms, but how did the constant become $108$?

Comment: Please include the work you did to get the first two terms. This will inform people of your thought process, and will also help them avoid spending time duplicating your effort or explaining things you already understand. Also, provide other context such as what you know about how the distance between directrices relates to other metric properties of a conic. This may provide a jumping-off place for explaining the constant term.

Comment: If you know the ellipse is centered on the origin and has major axis along the $x$-axis, you know the directrices are $x=\pm 12$ and the foci are $(\pm c,0)$ I.e.
$(x-c)^2+y^2=(\frac12)^2(x-12)^2$
 and 
$(x+c)^2+y^2=(\frac12)^2(x+12)^2$
must be the same equation so $c=3.$